# send an email without opening the MFMailComposeViewController form

Tags: objective-c, email, hook

I'd like to send an email to my email when a button is clicked without showing the user the email screen.
i.e without using this line:

so I guess my question is how to programmatically click on the send button of that control after filling the fields like so - and do it without being rejected from the store :)

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailCompose = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailCompose.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailCompose setSubject:emailTitle];
[mailCompose setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];

//instead of this line: [self presentViewController:mailCompose animated:YES completion:NULL];
// ?? --> call to send button click
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is you can't. Apple forbids sending SMS, emails and making phone calls without UI. Even if you find event which is called when user presses send button in MFMailComposeViewController, there is huge possibility that your app will be rejected in review process.

On the other hand you can take a look at [MailCore2](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2) library. It is powerful library for sending / receiving emails. Maybe overkill for your needs but definitely worth a shot.

Comment: What if I want to have my own custom UI? for example a customize form that send the result to email - like support form?

Comment: Then you need to make your own core for sending emails. Apple states that if you want to use MFMailComposeViewController you must present it's UI. Simple as that.